# Uploading file through mountain duck in S3 storage is slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In mountain duck i have connected AWS s3 storage bucket. In that bucket directories if i drop large files say 1GB using mountain duck, it is getting reflect in actual S3 storage only after few minutes not immediately.

Answer (score 0):

S3 storage uses eventual consistency for updates. While it is copying and making backups of your file it will display the previous version of the file.

If this is the first time you have uploaded the file then it is probably more likely to be that the backend is taking slightly longer than it is stated to upload the file.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Actually 
-> I am uploading files to AWS S3 using 'Mountain duck' or 'Cyberduck' app 
-> Then from AWS EC2 instance when i try to view the uploaded file using the command "aws s3 ls path" the upload file getting list only after few minutes. Not immediately.